# Ho can I purge all repository from Azure container registry without entering all repository one-by-ne

Tags: azure, containers, azure-container-registry, acr

I am trying to clean few Azure container registry images from all repository. For now I am entering repository name one-by-one but this looks vary tedious like this.

```
PURGE_CMD="acr purge --filter 'aag:.*' --filter 'aap_6.0:.*' --ago 1d --untagged --keep 7"

  az acr task create --name PurgeACRImages \
  --cmd "$PURGE_CMD" \
  --schedule "5 6 * * 1" \
  --registry myregistry \
  --timeout 18000 \
  --context /dev/null
```

Here I have given name of two repository, now I have 800 repository and it's really hard to type 800 repository in this PURGE_CMD command.

I need a command through which I can select all repo from ACR and store into PURGE_CMD

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can loop on the output of `az acr repository list` to concatenate repository name filters to the `PURGE_CMD` variable.

If you are using a Linux client, run the following from the command line:

```
PURGE_CMD="acr purge --ago 1d --untagged --keep 7"
for i in $(az acr repository list -n <yourRegistryName> -o tsv);do PURGE_CMD+=" --filter '"$i":.'";done
echo $PURGE_CMD
```

If you are using Windows Powershell run the following from the command line:

```
$PURGE_CMD="acr purge --ago 1d --untagged --keep 7"
 foreach ($i in $(az acr repository list -n <yourRegistryName> -o tsv)){$PURGE_CMD+=" --filter '"+$i+":.'"}
 echo $PURGE_CMD
```

**Note:** replace `<yourRegistryName>` with the name of your Azure Container Registry.

Finally you can run:

```
az acr task create --name PurgeACRImages
--cmd "$PURGE_CMD"
--schedule "5 6 * * 1"
--registry myregistry
--timeout 18000
--context /dev/null
```

Answer (score 3):

`$PURGE_CMD="acr purge --filter '.*:.*'  --ago 30d"` command looks good for me. So, there are 2 expressions: for repo name and for tag name

Comment: Just used this command, works just as well, a lot easier then the accepted answer. And when you create a scheduled purge task using this syntax it will also include purge repositories that are created afterwards.