# Azure Container Registery: How to clean all repositories

Tags: azure, azure-container-registry, purge

I want to clean azure container registry repositories with schedule.
This shows how to filter and more but this is only for one repository:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auto-purge

Then this subject show how to clean multiple repositories:
[Ho can I purge all repository from Azure container registry without entering all repository one-by-ne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68982004/ho-can-i-purge-all-repository-from-azure-container-registry-without-entering-all)

But mainly both of them doesnt conver for the future repositories.
How can i set a task or something else that cleans repositories including future repositories with the filter set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://www.danielstechblog.io/remove-dangling-container-manifests-from-azure-container-registry/). You can use a script to loop over your repos and delete the dangling images:

```
$ACRS = Get-AzContainerRegistry
foreach ($ACR in $ACRS) {
  $REPOS = Get-AzContainerRegistryRepository -RegistryName $ACR.Name
  foreach ($REPO in $REPOS) {
    $MANIFESTS = (Get-AzContainerRegistryManifest -RegistryName $ACR.Name -RepositoryName $REPO).ManifestsAttributes | Where-Object { $_.Tags -eq $null } | Sort-Object -Property LastUpdateTime -Descending
    foreach ($ITEM in $MANIFESTS) {
      $TAG = $ITEM.digest
      Write-OutPut "------------------------"
      Write-Output "Delete dangling image $REPO@$TAG"
      Remove-AzContainerRegistryManifest -RegistryName $ACR.Name -RepositoryName $REPO -Manifest $TAG
    }
  }
}
```

This can be used ad-hoc (e.g., run this in your Azure shell) or in the pipeline.